# match a node that has direct links to all nodes in a set

Tags: neo4j, cypher

When there is only 2 nodes in the set , it's relatively easy

```
MATCH (a:Article {id : "PMID:16009338"}),(c:Article {id: "PMID:21743479"}) 
WITH a, c 
MATCH (a)-[r]-(d)-[r1]-(c)
RETURN d
```

But a similar attempt with 3 nodes didn't work

```
MATCH (a:Article {id : "PMID:16009338"}),(c:Article {id: "PMID:21743479"}), (p:Article {id: "PMID:21741956"})  
WITH a, c, p
MATCH (a)-[r]-(d)-[r1]-(c)-[r2]-(d)-[r3]-(p) 
RETURN d
```

It looks for a different relation between c and d. r1 and r2. If I change r2 to r1 it says : Cannot use the same relationship variable 'r1' for multiple patterns.

Even If I make this to work it will be impossible for set of 4+ nodes.

==== 
Attempt with 3 nodes from different types which executes fast enough

```
MATCH (a:Article {id : "AID:16009338"}),(v:Video {id: "VID:21743479"}), (s:Song {id: "SID:21741956"})  
WITH a, v, s 
MATCH (a)-[]-(d) 
WITH d, v, s 
MATCH (v)-[]-(d) 
WITH d, s 
MATCH (s)-[]-(d) 
RETURN d
```

Answer (score 2):

You could look for the common node against a list of articles and then make sure the number that matched afterwards was the same as the number you were matching against.

```
WITH ['PMID:16009338','PMID:21743479','PMID:21741956'] as articles
MATCH (d)--(a:Article)
WHERE a.id in articles
WITH articles, d, COLLECT(a) AS matched
WHERE size(articles) = size(matched)
RETURN d
```

Comment: that is in fact working, but can we improve it if any of the nodes in the set has a different type, no Article, but Video or Song

Comment: The most convenient way from a querying perspective would be to add another more generic label to your nodes like `Content` and create an index on that.

Answer (score 0):

So you have X nodes that all need to connect to some other node D?

```
MATCH (a:Article {id : "AID:16009338"})--(d),(v:Video {id: "VID:21743479"})--(d), (s:Song {id: "SID:21741956"})--(d)
RETURN d
```

If you know the direction of the relations, add that in. And if you know the name of the relation, add that as well:

```
MATCH (a:Article {id : "AID:16009338"})-[:ART_TO_D]->(d),(v:Video {id: "VID:21743479"})-[:VID_TO_D]->(d), (s:Song {id: "SID:21741956"})-[:SONG_TO_D]->(d)
RETURN d
```